# sort array of arrays by number of elements in sub array

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

I have an array of arrays.  I want to sort the containing array so that the sub arrays with the most elements in the array are first.

Example:

```
$my_array = array(
  array(0=>”a", 1=>”b”, 4=>”c"),
  array(3=>”z"),
  array(0=>”p”, 2=>”k"),
);
```

Desired result: 
The sub array with 3 elements is ordered 1st and the sub array with 1 element is ordered last.

```php
$my_array = array(
  array(0=>”a", 1=>”b”, 4=>”c"),
  array(0=>”p”, 2=>”k"),
  array(3=>”z"),
);
```

Comment: Have you tried any code yet?

Answer (score 4):

Just use `usort()` with  the `count()` method.

```
<?php

$my_array = array(
  array(0=>"a", 1=>"b", 4=>"c"),
  array(3=>"z"),
  array(0=>"p", 2=>"k"),
);

usort($my_array, function($a, $b) {
    if (count($a) == count($b)) {
        return 0;
    }
    return (count($a) < count($b)) ? 1 : -1;
});

print_r($my_array);
```

[Example fiddle](http://3v4l.org/8CLMK)

Comment: Hi! Did my answer help you? I would appreciate if you could accept the answer if it did. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

A variant of this might do the trick.  [usort](http://pt1.php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php)

```
function compare($a, $b) {
  if (count($a) == count($b)) return 0;
  return (count($a) < count($b)) ? -1 : 1;
}

usort($my_array, 'compare');
```