# Laravel sort array according to number of elements in sub array

Tags: php, arrays, laravel

Is there any laravel collection methold that i dont know of, which would allow me to sort an array based on the number of elements on the sub array?

```
Illuminate\Support\Collection {#1143 ▼
  #items: array:7 [▼
    "A" => Illuminate\Support\Collection {#21181 ▼
      #items: array:10 [▶]
    }
    "B" => Illuminate\Support\Collection {#21182 ▼
      #items: array:8 [▶]
    }
    "C" => Illuminate\Support\Collection {#21183 ▼
      #items: array:9 [▶]
    }
    "D" => Illuminate\Support\Collection {#21184 ▼
      #items: array:5 [▶]
    }
    "E" => Illuminate\Support\Collection {#21185 ▼
      #items: array:2 [▶]
    }
    "F" => Illuminate\Support\Collection {#21186 ▼
      #items: array:4 [▶]
    }
    "G" => Illuminate\Support\Collection {#21187 ▼
      #items: array:15 [▶]
    }
  ]
}
```

I could do something like [THIS](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22411408/1364302) using `usort()` but I was just wondering if there exists any method within laravel collections, which I yet dont know or may be I am not able to locate it within [Laravel Collections](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/collections).

Comment: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php would be the most simple, there is a sort wrapper for it in collection, see: https://laravel.com/api/5.8/Illuminate/Support/Collection.html#method_sort

Comment: As far as documentation goes, there isn't. Use usort method.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if anyone is going to stumble into similar problem, I found a way around it as mentioned in the [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/collections#method-sortby)

I still don't know if this is the perfect way of doing it, but it did the trick for me. I am just posting it such that it might help someone a lot of headache and time.

I would still love to hear other answers and comments on the alternative ways of doing it.

```
$sorted = $mostWatchedVideosThisWeek->sortByDesc(function ($stats, $key) {
     return count($stats);
});
```

Comment: That would be the preferred way to do this in the Laravel way. An alternative way may be applied if that collection of collections is generated from a database query, where you could apply sorting at query level instead of php level.

Answer (score 0):

**if you searching for `usort()`, Laravel https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/collections#method-sort  work same  like `usort()`**

eg:

```
 $full_sorted = $collection_data->sort(function($a ,$b) { //$a first element ,$b second element
                if ((count($a) > count($b))) {
                        return -1; 
                }else{
                   return 1;
                }
            })->values();
```